# Is there an SSDT API for data comparison functionality that can be used in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, compare, sql-server-data-tools

I have a task : once in a week compare two databases on the same server and update,insert or delete from target.
I am doing this by using SSDT tool in visual studio 2012 - data compare. Does the job smoothly.

I want to automate the proccess - create an app which would be scheduled to do data comparison using SSDT tool.

Is there a way to use it in c# code?

Comment: Take a look to DacFX framework

Comment: Do you specifically need to use SSDT to do so? If you don't, it broadens the range of options quite a bit.

Comment: @sidux Unfortunately DacFx only deals with schema objects: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/12/23/dacfx-public-model-tutorial.aspx